# Entity Framework Core with .NET 6 - use sub method inside WhereIf

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have problem with Entity Framework Core

While I need to call function inside lambda expression like example below:

```
 var result = await (await GetQueryableAsync()).AsQueryable()
     .WhereIf(filter.Categories is not null, x=> FilterData(filter.Categories, x.CategoriesStr))
     .Skip(skipCount)
     .Take(maxRowCount)
     .ToListAsync();


private bool FilterData(Guid[] filter, Guid[] data) 
{
    // this method not called
    //TODO something here...
}
```

I got this error message:

```
[16:04:07 ERR] ---------- RemoteServiceErrorInfo ----------
{
  "code": null,
  "message": "An internal error occurred during your request!",
  "details": null,
  "data": {},
  "validationErrors": null
}
[16:04:07 ERR] The LINQ expression 'DbSet<DraftMessage>()
    .Where(d => __ef_filter__p_0 || !(EF.Property<bool>(d, "IsDeleted")) && __ef_filter__p_1 || (Guid?)EF.Property<Guid>(d, "TenantId") == __ef_filter__CurrentTenantId_2)
    .Where(d => d.MailboxId == __mailboxId_0)
    .Where(d => d.CorrespondenceCategories
        .StringSperatorFilterArray(__filter_Categories_1))' could not be translated. Additional information: Translation of method 't2.OLE5.Helpers.Extension.CollectionExtension.StringSperatorFilterArray' failed. If this method can be mapped to your custom function, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2132413 for more information. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<DraftMessage>()
    .Where(d => __ef_filter__p_0 || !(EF.Property<bool>(d, "IsDeleted")) && __ef_filter__p_1 || (Guid?)EF.Property<Guid>(d, "TenantId") == __ef_filter__CurrentTenantId_2)
    .Where(d => d.MailboxId == __mailboxId_0)
    .Where(d => d.CorrespondenceCategories
        .StringSperatorFilterArray(__filter_Categories_1))' could not be translated. Additional information: Translation of method 't2.OLE5.Helpers.Extension.CollectionExtension.StringSperatorFilterArray' failed. If this method can be mapped to your custom function, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2132413 for more information. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

As you see in the codes, the function named 'FilterData' isn't called.

Why is the function not called? How can I solve this issue with an example?

**Notes**: I need to hit the database once. As you see, I have pagination in my code.

Please help - many thanks

Comment: `FilterData` is a c# method (for which no equivalent SQL Server method exists), so it can only be called *after* getting the data from SQL Server. Which means that you need to need to call `ToList(Async)` *before* calling `WhereIf`. Note that this will cause your pagination code to be executed in C# after getting *all* data from SQL Server, which might or might not be what you want. If you need pagination to happen on the SQL Server side, you must find a way to filter the data with expressions that SQL Server understands (i.e., not with custom C# code).

Comment: @Heinzi thank you for fast response, but what you mean in this (for which no equivalent SQL Server method exists) please let me know?

Comment: Do you understand *in principle* how Entity Framework queries work, i.e., when and where LINQ statements are translated to SQL? I'm asking so that I know which level of background knowledge I can assume in my answer.